# Django model object's boolean value not getting rendered

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to show a field value in Django template. All values are getting rendered successfully but the one boolean value is not getting rendered.

template.html

```
{{user.username}}{{user.email}}  /*{{user.is_email_confirmed}} This is not working*/
```

Comment: This is not an attribute of Django's standard `User` model. Do you use a custom `User` model? If yes, can you share (relvant parts) of it.

Comment: I was so silly, the variable was coming from its inherited class Profile so i just did user.profile.is_email_confirmed. And it worked. Thanks for pointing it out.